# HtmlHelpers Html.LabelFor/TextBoxFor/EditorFor are unrecognized in ASP.NET Core Razor Pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

I have a .NET 5.0 MVC project migrated from .NET Core 3.1, but forms using `Html.LabelFor`, `Html.TextBoxFor`, or `Html.EditorFor` do not show inputs.

**View:**

```
@model UpdateProductsViewModel;

@{
    using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateProducts", "TheController", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <p>Browse File:</p>
        Html.LabelFor(m => m.FullName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "this-doesnt-show"});
        Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FullName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "this-neither");
        Html.EditorFor(m => m.FullName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "this-neither");
        <div>
            <label asp-for="FullName" class="this-shows-with-asp-for"></label>
            <input asp-for="FullName" class="this-shows-with-asp-for" />
        </div>
        <input type='submit' value="Submit" />
    }
}
```

**Model:**

```
public class UpdateProductsViewModel{
  // truncated

  public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

In my sample above, I have the model and view.

However *before* I changed it to `asp-for`, I had them as `Html.LabelFor, Html.EditorFor, Html.TextboxFor`.  ***These have never shown again in .NET 5***.

When I use the syntax `<input asp-for=""> | <label asp-for="">` the controls show, in other words 1x label, 1x input text box, but *none of the others (HtmlHelper syntax)*.

- Are these Helpers not available anymore, even though IntelliSense detects the keywords in VS Code, or am I missing some references or some attributes on the ViewModel?

Please note I do not use .NET MVC with Razor that regularly, so maybe something changed that I am not aware of.

Comment: Prefix the Html helpers with `@` and remove the trailing semi-colon e.g. `@Html.LabelFor(...)`

Comment: You are correct, I thought I didn't need the `@` before each helper function because of the initial `@{  }`.  Thanks!

Comment: The `@` prior to the method call ensures that the result is rendered. The `@{ ... }` notation is for opening a code block.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I don't use this enough to know the difference. _I thought its just a code block section, and didn't really it is tied to **rendering**_ when used with helpers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use razor syntax. Something like this

```
@model UpdateProductsViewModel;

@{
    using (Html.BeginForm("UpdateProducts", "TheController", FormMethod.Post))
    {
        <p>Browse File:</p>
         @Html.LabelFor(m => m.FullName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "this-doesnt- 
         show"})
         @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FullName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = 
         "thisneither")
          @Html.EditorFor(m => m.FullName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = 
          "thisneither")
        <input type='submit' value="Submit" />
    }
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned I tried _Razor syntax_, but it didn't work.  But thanks for the example, the missing `@` before each helper function was my issue.  For some reason I thought the outer `@ {  }`  meant that I don't need to prefix the helper functions